# Getting error: cannot find symbol method getCardDescription() on maven project w/spring-boot, was working just added one getter/setter

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, h2, flyway

Quick intro, project was working and building fine and all test were running fine. I added one Variable to my Card.java class, and then added it to appropriate classes along with the other variables and now when I try to run man clean install I get the error: cannot find symbol  method getCardDescription()location: variable card of type Card

Here are some snippets to help see what was done.

```
package com.
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class Card {

private Long id;
private String cardName;
private String cardNumber;
private byte[] cardImage;
private String cardImageMimeType;
private String cardType;
private String cardDescription; // this is the new variable added

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
}

public void setCardName(String cardName) {
    this.cardName = cardName;
}

public String getCardNumber() {
    return cardNumber;
}

public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
}

public byte[] getCardImage() {
    return cardImage;
}

public void setCardImage(byte[] cardImage) {
    this.cardImage = cardImage;
}

public String getCardImageMimeType() {
    return cardImageMimeType;
}

public void setCardImageMimeType(String cardImageMimeType) {
    this.cardImageMimeType = cardImageMimeType;
}

public String getCardType() {
    return cardType;
}

public void setCardType(String cardType) { this.cardType = cardType; }

public String getCardDescription() { return cardDescription; } // this   
is the new getter added

public void setCardDescription(String cardDescription) { this.cardDescription = cardDescription; } // this is the new setter added


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Card)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    final Card otherObject = (Card) obj;

    return new EqualsBuilder()
            // intentionally ignoring id as this is the database key
            .append(this.cardName, otherObject.cardName)
            .append(this.cardNumber, otherObject.cardNumber)
            .append(this.cardImage, otherObject.cardImage)
            .append(this.cardImageMimeType, otherObject.cardImageMimeType)
            .append(this.cardType, otherObject.cardType)
            .append(this.cardDescription, otherObject.cardDescription) // this is the new variable added
            .isEquals();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(this.id)
            .append(this.cardName)
            .append(this.cardNumber)
            .append(this.cardImage)
            .append(this.cardImageMimeType)
            .append(this.cardType)
            .append(this.cardDescription) // this is the new variable added
            .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

}
```

this is the 
    package com.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.learnvest.qacodechallenge.commons.db.BaseRowMapper;
import com.learnvest.qacodechallenge.commons.model.card.Card;

public class CardDaoRowMapper extends BaseRowMapper<Card> {

@Override
public Map<String, Object> mapObject(Card card) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id", card.getId());
    map.put("card_name", card.getCardName());
    map.put("card_number", card.getCardNumber());
    map.put("card_image", card.getCardImage());
    map.put("card_image_mime_type", card.getCardImageMimeType());
    map.put("card_type", card.getCardType());
    map.put("card_description", card.getCardDescription());  // added for the new getter
    return map;
}

@Override
public Card mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    Card card = new Card();
    card.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
    card.setCardName(resultSet.getString("card_name"));
    card.setCardNumber(resultSet.getString("card_number"));
    card.setCardImage(resultSet.getBytes("card_image"));
     card.setCardImageMimeType(resultSet.getString("card_image_mime_type"));
    card.setCardType(resultSet.getString("card_type"));
    card.setCardDescription(resultSet.getString("card_description"));  // added for the new setter
    return card;
}

}
```

Here is the error message when building

```
Williams-MBP:service williambigno$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building service 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ service ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/william/projectCodeChallenge/code-challenge-william-bigno/service/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ service ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
Audit done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @    service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ service ---
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to  /Users/william/projectCodeChallenge/code-challenge-william-bigno/service/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/william/projectCodeChallenge/code-challenge-william- bigno/service/src/main/java/com/learnvest/qacodechallenge/service/db/CardDaoRowMapper.java:[22,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getCardDescription()
 location: variable card of type Card
/Users/william/projectCodeChallenge/code-challenge-william- bigno/service/src/main/java/com/learnvest/qacodechallenge/service/db/CardDaoRowMapper.java:[35,12] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.215 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-11T15:24:50-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/294M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/william/projectCodeChallenge/code-challenge-william-bigno/service/src/main/java/com/learnvest/qacodechallenge/service/db/CardDaoRowMapper.java:[22,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getCardDescription()
[ERROR]   location: variable card of type Card
[ERROR] /Users/william/projectCodeChallenge/code-challenge-william-bigno/service/src/main/java/com/learnvest/qacodechallenge/service/db/CardDaoRowMapper.java:[35,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Williams-MBP:service william$
```

I did a migration with Flyway to add the new column which ran fine, but just incase here is that code, and response

```
Williams-MBP:service william$ mvn flyway:migrate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building service 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:5.0.7:migrate (default-cli) @ service ---
[INFO] Flyway Community Edition 5.0.7 by Boxfuse
[INFO] Database: jdbc:h2:file:./target/migration (H2 1.4)
[INFO] Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.013s)
[INFO] Creating Schema History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history"
[INFO] Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
[INFO] Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 001.001 - service
[INFO] Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 002.001 - alter card table
[INFO] Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.098s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.812 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-11T13:46:43-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Incase you want to see me SQL statements

```
--STATEMENT createCard
INSERT INTO card (
 card_name,
 card_number,
 card_image,
 card_image_mime_type,
 card_type,
 card_description
) VALUES(
 :card_name,
 :card_number,
 :card_image,
 :card_image_mime_type,
 :card_type,
 :card_description
);

--STATEMENT readCard
SELECT * FROM card WHERE id = :id;

--STATEMENT updateCard
UPDATE card
 SET
 card_name = :card_name,
 card_number = :card_number,
 card_image = :card_image,
 card_image_mime_type = :card_image_mime_type,
 card_type = :card_type,
 card_description = :card_description
 WHERE id = :id
;

--STATEMENT deleteCard
DELETE FROM card WHERE id = :id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to close this out as I was able to find the issue, which was with maven not reloading the dependencies when running `mvn clean install` So I had to run `mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies` and then I was able to do the install and it found the new getter and setters and worked fine.

Hope this helps out anyone else that finds themselves stuck on the same error with using maven.